# Do the neurogenic chemicals in mushrooms get transmitted to milk?

Tags: mycology, nutrition, milk

In a [recent video by SciShow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSUURvSBR-4) they discussed several studies showing that several compounds in lion's mane mushrooms encourage neuron growth. Do we know if these chemicals get passed into milk if a lactating female consumes them? I'm curious about both human breast milk for supplementation purposes (and possible safety concerns about whether this could cause overgrowth in an already rapidly developing infant brain) and ruminant milk (cows, goats, and sheep for possible commercial applications).

List of sources SciShow used:

1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3924982/
2. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3449638/
3. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4583117/
4. https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/52615
5. https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/20/4/859/htm
6. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5237458/
7. https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/biomedres/40/4/40_125/_pdf/-char/en
8. https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bpb/31/9/31_9_1727/_pdf/-char/en